# Set CSS of input with largest value

Tags: javascript, css

I have 4 inputs that receive values. They are of `type="text"` because those inputs might receive `3*3` inputs, transform to `9` by previous function.

How can I find the input with the max value, ignoring `null` value(s), in order to manipulate the CSS of the element?

What I have so far:

```js
function whichis() {
    let max = [...document.querySelectorAll("#results input")].sort((a, b) => {
        return b.value === '' ? 1 : (a.value === '' ? -1 : (b.value - a.value))
}, '')[0];

    document.getElementById(max.id).style.border ="1px solid red";
}
```

```html
<div id="results">
<input type="text" id="a5"><br>
<input type="text" id="b5"><br>
<input type="text" id="c5"><br>
<input type="text" id="d5" onblur="whichis()">
</div>
```

EDIT: Thanks to @Ele's answer, I can determine which input `id` has the largest value, but when a value is `null` that one returns the largest.

How do I ignore/skip `null` values?

Comment: What is impure javascript? But yes, surely there is a way. What have you tried?

Comment: Can you post the HTML of your inputs? Can you grab them in a group by class name or any other attribute? Also, take a look into [converting strings to numbers](https://coderwall.com/p/5tlhmw/converting-strings-to-number-in-javascript-pitfalls) and [`Math.max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use the following to find the max value**

*Basically, find your input elements, then sort them in descending direction and get the first element.*

```
let max = [...document.querySelectorAll('input')].filter((input) => !isNaN(input.value)).sort((a, b) => {
  return (b.value - a.value);
}, '')[0];
```

**This is assuming your input fields are declared as follow:**

```
<input type='number' id='xyz' value='xyzvalue'>
```

## Look at this code snippet

```js
let max = [...document.querySelectorAll('input')].filter((input) => !isNaN(input.value)).sort((a, b) => {
  return (b.value - a.value);
}, '')[0];

document.getElementById(max.id).classList.add('green')
console.log(max.id);
```

```css
.green {
  background-color: green
}
```

```html
<input type='number' id='id45' value='45'><br>
<input type='number' id='id47' value='47'><br>
<input type='number' id='id59' value='null'><br>
<input type='number' id='id23' value='23'>
```

Comment: Thanks, an issue remain, in case there is an input with `value = null` (left empty), this input is returned the max one.
As I barely understant how the code is working, I have no idea how to skip `null` value(s)...

Comment: @Chismah see the updated answer.  First, filter the valid numbers and then sort it.